# How do you set a laptop's screen color profile to 9300k in Windows 7?

Tags: laptop, display, colors, color-profiles

I have a large LCD monitor in which I have set on 9300k color. I like this profile a lot and much prefer it over the default 6500k profile but I have no idea how to set my laptop to it as well. The laptop does not appear to have any hardware-related buttons for doing this and I saw nothing in the BIOS, so I'm assuming the only way to do it is through Windows 7. Help?

Comment: It might POSSIBLY help to mention what make a model of laptop you're using.

Comment: Toshiba Qosmio x505-Q880.